# Attaching arguments of any type to event

Tags: c++, events, generic-programming

I have little experience with generic programming (I've rarely needed it), but I'm now trying to implement an event system for my application. This is what I had in mind for the actual events:

```
template <typename Arg_Type> struct Event {
    std::vector<std::string> ids; // All the objects to pass the event to
    Action action;                // Action to perform (enum)
    std::vector<Arg_Type> args;   // List of event-dependant arguments
};
```

But then I'd like to store my various events in a vector:

```
std::vector<Event*> events;
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be that straightforward!

How would I go about achieving the desired effect? That is, being able to pass around events with varying kinds of argument types?

I know I could do something like this:

```
struct Event {};

struct EventFloat : public Event {};

struct EventString : public Event {};
```

But it just seems inelegant and harder to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `Event<>` classes inherit from a common parent, say `EventInterface`.  The `EventInterface` would be an abstract class that defines the interface to all events.

```
class EventInterface
{
    public:
        virtual void tweak  ( int t ) = 0;
        virtual void twiddle( int t ) = 0;
        virtual void frob   ( int f ) = 0;

        virtual ~EventInterface() {};
};

template <typename Arg_Type> struct Event : public EventInterface {
};
```

Then make your vector a `std::vector<EventInterface *>` or the like.

From a maintenance standpoint, it's not really that bad, because all the common interface class does is define a common interface for all events to adhere to.  And if you did want to add new, non-template event classes, you could.

The downside is that you can't make `ArgType` part of the common interface.  However, that makes a certain amount of sense:  How else would you be able to legally invoke an arbitrary method on an `Event*` if you didn't know the types of the arguments?

Now you could require that all `Arg_Type` be subclasses of some common `EventArgument` class, and define your interface in terms of that.  The template would still buy you something.  It all depends on how you want to define your event interface.

Working example:

```
class EventArgument 
{
     public:
         virtual int getId () = 0;
         virtual ~EventArgument() { };
};

class EventInterface
{
    public:
        virtual void tweak  ( int t ) = 0;
        virtual void twiddle( int t ) = 0;
        virtual void frob   ( int f ) = 0;
        virtual EventArgument& getArg() = 0;

        virtual ~EventInterface() {};
};

class fredArg   : public EventArgument
{
    public:
    virtual int getId() { return 1; }
    ~fredArg() { };
};
class barneyArg : public EventArgument
{
    public:
    virtual int getId() { return 2; }
    ~barneyArg() { };
};

template <typename Arg_Type>
struct Event : public EventInterface
{

    Arg_Type arg;

    Event() { };

    virtual void tweak  ( int t ) { };
    virtual void twiddle( int t ) { };
    virtual void frob   ( int f ) { };

    virtual EventArgument& getArg()
    {
        return arg;
    }
};

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<EventInterface*> events;

int main()
{
    events.push_back( new Event<fredArg>(  ) );
    events.push_back( new Event<barneyArg>(  ) );

    std::cout << events[0]->getArg().getId() << std::endl;
    std::cout << events[1]->getArg().getId() << std::endl;
}
```

This prints `1` and `2` as you would expect.